# ImageView resizes when keyboard open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bgImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/default_wallpaper" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_out"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="none" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this when I tap on `EditText` soft keyboard opens but my `ImageView` is shrinking.

I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest file but by using this it will push up whole activity upper side but I want ImageView as it is and when keyboard is open ImageView is cut from bottom not from top as in `WhatsApp` application.

Any help will appreciate. Thank you ..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in which a custom View - `ParallaxBackground` - that I've adapted was supposed to act as a background image with a parallax effect driven by the scroll of a `ViewPager` in the same activity.

In other words, I have a View that displays an image with a width slightly larger than the screen's and when the user scrolls along the `ViewPager`,  the image in the `ParallaxBackground` scrolls a little as well.

Now in my case, I had some EditTexts inside my ViewPager's Fragments and when the user clicked on them, causing the soft keyboard to show up, the ParallaxBackground (and consequently, the background image) would be re-sized and *squeezed* "against my will".

So I added a `boolean isBackground`, two `int`s for `fixedWidth` and `fixedHeight` and overrode my View's `onMeasure()` like so:

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


    if(isBackground) 
    // If this is being used as a background and is supposed to occupy the whole screen...
    {
                    // force the View to have the specified dimensions
        setMeasuredDimension(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
    }
    // ...aply default measures...
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

 }
```

I know this is not a "beautiful" solution but, even though my answer is not 100% related to your problem, you might want to try extending the `ImageView` class and overriding `onMeasure`.

Then, in your `onCreate` method you can set `isBackground` to true and give `fixedWidth` and `fixedHeight` the values for your measured screen width and height.

Answer (score 1):

remove the parent layout (the `RelativeLayout`) and make the `LinearLayout` containing the dialog box only, the parent! plus, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Well If I remove RelativeLayout then how can I put IMageView in background of all controls ?

Answer (score 0):

Add background image from Java not from XML:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_image));
```

In manifest add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

The state hidden can written as per requirement if you have to hide the keyboard on opening of screen